# Can we create a toggle switch using field parameter in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a field parameter which contains two measures:

```
Parameter = {
    ("Sales Price", NAMEOF('Measure'[Sales Price]), 0),
    ("Unit Sold", NAMEOF('Measure'[Unit Sold]), 1)
}
```

I can use the Slicer visual and turn on single selection to use one measure at a time. It will look something like:

[image]

But my requirement is to create a toggle button like:

[image]

I am aware that I can use bookmarks, but I wanted to know if it's possible using Field parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this custom visual: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200002754?tab=Overview

- Add Parameter in the Data field
- In Visual properties, under Switch, set Value(s) for ON: `Sales Price` and `Unit Sold` for OFF (or the other way round)

And if you don't want to use a custom visual, then you can use bookmarks. You will need to add the Parameter slicer, set it to each, and hide, for each bookmark.

Comment: I tried to use the custom visual. Also followed the steps you shared and added the Parameter to other visuals where I need to apply the change. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It won't work if you have the Parameter slicer with a selected value.

Comment: Great, now it's working, thanks!